How to share camera views from one phone to another programatically?
I am building an android application that can open multiple cameras using Camera2 API simultaneously. Now I want to stream the footage of those cameras over RSTP. I found this "libstreaming" library for this purpose but the main issue I am facing is that I can integrate it with my android studio project. I tried to import the library as a module but it always kept on giving "Specify location of gradle or eclipse project".
Then I also tried to manually create build.gradle and settings.gradle files in the root of project directory but it also didn't work. The instruction to specify went away but still android studio wouldn't allow me finish the import. Finally I tried to manually copy paste the library and then include it in my project's setting.gradle but it didn't work too.
I took reference from following links: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/issues/153 How to import libstreaming in Android Studio?
I am facing these issues in Android Studio Koala // 2024.1.1
